# styling of background color in pixel phone

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to put the logo of the company  so that it stretches out from top left corner to the top right corner with width of 10. Below is my code. My image is not showing properly. It shows in the middle of the screen with width going outside of the phone.If I put position: absolute then the image disappears from the phone.

```
  /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTheme } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import getDirections from 'react-native-google-maps-directions'
const theme = getTheme();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
  },

  container: {     
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#4F6D7A', 
    height: 550,
    alignSelf:'center',
    width:500,
    position: 'relative',
  }, 

  title1: {
      top: 10,
      left: 80,
      fontSize: 24,
  },
  title2: {
      top: 35,
      left: 82,
      fontSize: 18,
  },
  image: {
      flex: 0,
      height: 100,
      width: 333,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  closeIcon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 5,
      left: 295,
      color: 'rgba(233,166,154,0.8)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },  
  icon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 15,
      left: 0,
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
  },
  textArea: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingTop: 10,
      width: 260,
  },
  textIcons: {
      color: '#26a69a',
  },
  actionArea: {
      paddingTop: 10,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },

  title:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#F5FCFF', 
    },

    SerContent:{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingTop: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: '#F5FCFF'
    },

    underLineText: {
        fontSize: 17,
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        color:  '#F5FCFF',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',

      },

      dir:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        paddingTop: 30,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 17,
        alignSelf: 'center'

    } ,   

    Address1:{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginRight: 20,
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color:  '#F5FCFF',
    },
    toolbar: {
        flexDirection: 'row',   //Step 1

      },
      toolbarTitle:{
        width: 10,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        flex:1 ,
         position:'absolute'              //Step 3
      },

});
class ServiceDetail extends Component {
    handleClick = (link) => {
        Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(suppported => {
            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(link);
            } else {
                console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + link);
            }
        });
    };



  render() {




var destUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + this.props.services.destAddr1 + '+' + 'field'
var destUrl1 = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' + this.props.services.destAddr2 + '+' + 'field'
 return (

      <ScrollView  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.toolbar}>
              <Image 
                   resizeMode='contain'
                   style={styles.toolbarTitle} 
                  source={require('../Resources/LogoWithDesc.jpg')} />
           </View>



        <SimpleIcon name={'close'} size={30} style={styles.closeIcon}
            onPress={() => this.props.noneSelected()} />
        <Text  style={styles.title}>{this.props.services.ser}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.SerContent} >Service is available in the following locations:</Text>
        <View style={styles.dir}>
        <Text style={styles.Address1}> {this.props.services.Location}:</Text>   


        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(destUrl)}>
                <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Directions</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dir}>
        <Text  style={styles.Address1}>{this.props.services.SecondLoc}:</Text> 

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(destUrl1)}></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => Linking.openURL(destUrl1)}>
                <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Directions</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>


        </View>

      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        services: state.serviceSelected
     };
  };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceDetail);
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try increasing flex to Image and add the position property.

```
  image: {
  flex: 1,
  height: 200,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  width: 333,
  position: 'absolute',
  },
```

Please apply the width of the container and add the position property.

```
   container: {     
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#4F6D7A', 
    height: 200,
    alignSelf:'center'
    width: 333,
    position: 'relative',
    },
```

you can also edit the layout using flexbox
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

Comment: I used the above style sheet. By adjusting the height and width, the container is now filled with blue color, but my image is still not showing properly. This image should be at the top of the phone stretching from top left corner all the way to the top right corner with width of 10. I updated my code above to show the color in entire phone

Comment: try giving the image z-index property like zIndex: '100' in camelCase